# Does your hat change your hitbox?

Tags: rocket-league

In rocket league, there are a ton of Hats (not as much as TF2, but I digress)

Does these hats change the hitbox of the car? Like if I have a big sombrero on, could the ball react differently when hit with the roof of the car that if I have the police light, or no hat at all?

EDIT: I don't know if I am unclear with what I'm asking, but it feels so. Anybody get what I'm asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** Hat's do not alter your hitbox.

The various car models [only slightly alter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/228480/are-all-cars-completely-equal-in-regard-to-gameplay?rq=1) the hitbox.

Comment: So if you would be to 'head' the ball, the ball will just go though the hat and hit the roof of your car? Can't really verify by slowmoing a replay right now, I'm at work.

Comment: Yes. (From my experience).